# Extract zip code from string based on conditions (lenght and composition)

Tags: python, string, extract

Here's my string

```
str = "85 ch. Osborne L'Ange-Gardien (Québec) J8L4C1 Canada"
```

I'm trying to extract `J8L4C1`

Is there a way to extract a substring based on some conditions (e.g. `len(str) = 6` and `str = string integer string integer string integer`)

Using split wouldn't work since the zip code might be placed somewhere else in the string.

Comment: try `r'[A-Z0-9]{6}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
r"(?:[A-Z][0-9]){3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent partial matches, you can use word boundaries `\b` on the left and the right side, and repeat 3 times a char A-Z followed by a digit `\d`

```
\b(?:[A-Z]\d){3}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/taen50/1)